# Can't diagnose the issues with my novice level encrypting and decrypting program. Any Ideas?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, rsa

My encryption and Decryption code will not work.

```
import rsa

def maine():
    menu = input("Would you like encode, decode, or generate keys? E/D/G ")
    if(menu == 'e' or menu == 'E'):
        encoder()
    elif(menu == 'd' or menu == 'D'):
        decoder()
    elif(menu == 'G' or menu == 'g'):
        key_maker()
    else:
        maine()
        
def key_maker():
    (pubKey,privKey) = rsa.newkeys(512)
    print("Your public key is: ")
    print(pubKey)
    print("Your private key is: ")
    print(privKey)  
    print("KEEP YOUR PRIVATE KEY PRIVATE")
    y = input("When you're finished, press 'Y'")
    if(y == 'Y' or y == 'y'):
        boing()
    else:
        maine()
    
def boing():
    x = input("Enter 'Y' to return to the menu or 'N' to quit")
    if(x == 'y' or x == 'Y'):
        maine()
    elif (x == 'n' or x == 'N'):
        exit()
        
    
def encoder():
    message = (input("Enter your message you wish to be encoded: "))
    userKey = input("Enter your public key: ")
    encMessage = rsa.encrypt(message.encode(), userKey)
    print("Encryted message: ", encMessage)
    y = input("When you're finished, press 'Y'")
    if(y == 'Y' or y == 'y'):
        boing()
    else:
        maine()

def decoder():
    userPriv = ("Enter your private key: ")
    preMessage = byte(input("Enter the message you wish to decode: "))
    decMessage = rsa.decrpyt(encMessage, privKey).decode()
    print(decMessage)
    y = input("When you're finished, press 'Y'")
    if(y == 'Y' or y == 'y'):
        boing()
    else:
        maine()
    
z = input("Enter 'Start' to access the menu.")
if(z == 'Start'):
    maine()
else: 
    exit()

def decoder():
    userPriv = ("Enter your private key: ")
    preMessage = byte(input("Enter the message you wish to decode: "))
    decMessage = rsa.decrpyt(encMessage, privKey).decode()
    print(decMessage)
    y = input("When you're finished, press 'Y'")
    if(y == 'Y' or y == 'y'):
        boing()
    else:
        maine()
    
z = input("Enter 'Start' to access the menu.")
if(z == 'Start'):
    maine()
else: 
    exit()
```

Here is my crappy code with no comments throughout, and below I have put in the error that comes from trying to encode a message. I can successfully generate the RSA keys, but that's where my success falls.

Here is a sample run of obtaining a key and attempting to encode:

```
Enter 'Start' to access the menu.Start
Would you like encode, decode, or generate keys? E/D/G G
Your public key is: 
PublicKey(6801298121273416580196010647844979359757676488283126810140145424246540021728735623356604640255177030066898060245897988711965431993387215031796508033617091, 65537)
Your private key is: 
PrivateKey(6801298121273416580196010647844979359757676488283126810140145424246540021728735623356604640255177030066898060245897988711965431993387215031796508033617091, 65537, 6167110825255871548815602312569018164288259807325832641399335977864029281070356842844125435470183834106567935792265196213665608361608369946318331915626929, 5683435982112202966111823092757512330745461770863367013506321624310017318325853413, 1196687733033243246099441550050066276000669852283808973396502971911606407)
KEEP YOUR PRIVATE KEY PRIVATE
When you're finished, press 'Y'Y
Enter 'Y' to return to the menu or 'N' to quitY
Would you like encode, decode, or generate keys? E/D/G E
Enter your message you wish to be encoded: DOG
Enter your public key: 6801298121273416580196010647844979359757676488283126810140145424246540021728735623356604640255177030066898060245897988711965431993387215031796508033617091
```

And here is my error message that comes up after entering the public key:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[36], line 59
     57 z = input("Enter 'Start' to access the menu.")
     58 if(z == 'Start'):
---> 59     maine()
     60 else: 
     61     exit()

Cell In[36], line 10, in maine()
      8     decoder()
      9 elif(menu == 'G' or menu == 'g'):
---> 10     key_maker()
     11 else:
     12     maine()

Cell In[36], line 23, in key_maker()
     21 y = input("When you're finished, press 'Y'")
     22 if(y == 'Y' or y == 'y'):
---> 23     boing()
     24 else:
     25     maine()

Cell In[36], line 30, in boing()
     28 x = input("Enter 'Y' to return to the menu or 'N' to quit")
     29 if(x == 'y' or x == 'Y'):
---> 30     maine()
     31 elif (x == 'n' or x == 'N'):
     32     exit()

Cell In[36], line 6, in maine()
      4 menu = input("Would you like encode, decode, or generate keys? E/D/G ")
      5 if(menu == 'e' or menu == 'E'):
----> 6     encoder()
      7 elif(menu == 'd' or menu == 'D'):
      8     decoder()

Cell In[36], line 38, in encoder()
     36 message = (input("Enter your message you wish to be encoded: "))
     37 userKey = input("Enter your public key: ")
---> 38 encMessage = rsa.encrypt(message.encode(), userKey)
     39 print("Encryted message: ", encMessage)
     40 y = input("When you're finished, press 'Y'")

File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rsa/pkcs1.py:194, in encrypt(message, pub_key)
    172 def encrypt(message: bytes, pub_key: key.PublicKey) -> bytes:
    173     """Encrypts the given message using PKCS#1 v1.5
    174 
    175     :param message: the message to encrypt. Must be a byte string no longer than
   (...)
    191 
    192     """
--> 194     keylength = common.byte_size(pub_key.n)
    195     padded = _pad_for_encryption(message, keylength)
    197     payload = transform.bytes2int(padded)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Bear with me as it has been months since I've touched python. Just starting to get back into it as a little hobby. Thank you guys